# How to run the circle method in sleep mode, even when the screen is not active?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I do so that the method starts when the application is in sleep mode.
App.xaml.cs

```
protected override void OnSleep()
{

 var startTimeSpan = TimeSpan.Zero;
 var periodTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
 SleepCS sleep = new SleepCS();
 var timer = new System.Threading.Timer(async (e) =>
  {
    await sleep.NoticeUser();
  }, null, startTimeSpan, periodTimeSpan);

}
```

I want the method to work even when the screen is locked.

I found out that the process of my application is being killed by the system, if another application was running that needs more memory. something like this. It is necessary that the process of my application is not killed.

Comment: what do you mean by circle method? do you mean background process?

Comment: @Ali123 Yes. It works when after it was not running any application that requires more memory. I found out that the process of my application is being killed by the system, if another application was running that needs more memory. It is necessary that the process of my application is not killed.

Answer (score 0):

Your process is being killed because it was in the ram. You need to create a background process to do whatever you need to do even if the app is closed. Note that the background process can still be terminated from the system if user choose so.

Check this plugin for background processing by @winstongubantes
https://github.com/winstongubantes/MatchaBackgroundService